# FileUploading In CK-editor

Tags: javascript, file-upload, ckeditor, fckeditor, ckeditor4.x

**CKEDITOR.replace( 'bodyDetails',{

                    removeButtons: 'Source,Strike',

                    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/browser/browse.php',

                    filebrowserUploadUrl : '/uploader/upload.php'

                });**

I just use ck-editor for fileupload.
When I Uploade image in CK-Editor then It will Show me Some alert message **"Image source URL is missing."**
I don't want to pass URL. I need to pass some image with my local machine. I research some article but not found any proper solution. So Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CKEditor for uploading files/images even from your local machine You have to pass the full URL where the images has been stored.

For example, in my case, All my images are stored in a folder named `uploaded`

So, for uploading any image I have to enter full path like

`http://10.11.201.93:81/webdocument/uploaded/loan.png`

for the specific folder in the URL section and select the appropriate images you wanna upload.

Here's the example image:-

[image]

Even if you want to upload images directly form your local machine. First, You have to send the images to the server from the **upload** tab of the same dialog window. Then you could upload it to the editor from the server itself.

Comment: Thanks for give me answer. My problem is that I don't want to pass Url. I just upload some images which is stored in my local machine .

Comment: var SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();